# Access property in nested form

Tags: angular, forms

So I've this code:
TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } 
    from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hotel',
  templateUrl: './hotel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hotel.component.scss']
})
export class HotelComponent {
  click:boolean = false

  showForm = () => {
    this.click = true
  }


  hotelRegUser = this.fb.group({
    "userName": ["", Validators.required],
    "userNumber": ["", Validators.required],
    "userComingDate": ["", Validators.required],
    "userDays": ["", Validators.required],
    "userBreakfast": ["", Validators.required],

    extraAct: this.fb.group({
      "pool": [""],
      "kino": [""],
      "resturant": [""]
    })
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  submit = () => {
    console.log("reactive form submitted");
    console.log(this.hotelRegUser["controls"]["extraAct"]);
  }

  totalPrice = () => {
    let price = 0
    price += Number(this.hotelRegUser.controls["userDays"].value)*1200
    if (this.hotelRegUser.controls["userBreakfast"].value == "true"){
      price += Number(this.hotelRegUser.controls["userDays"].value)*300
    }
    return price
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<h3>Velkommen til Fredrikstad Hotell!</h3>

<ng-template [ngIf]="click == true">
    <p>For bestilling fyll ut skjemaet <button (click)="showForm()" mat-raised-button color="primary">her</button></p>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="click == false">
    <section class="sample-app-content">
        <form [formGroup]="hotelRegUser" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
            <h4>Navn</h4>
            <input type="text" formControlName="userName" required placeholder="Ola Normann" id="name">
        
            <h4>Telefonnummer</h4>
            <input type="number" formControlName="userNumber" required placeholder="00 00 00 00">
        
            <h4>Innskjekkingsdato</h4>
            <input type="date" formControlName="userComingDate" required id="date">
        
            <h4>Antall døgn</h4>
            <label for="days">Velg: </label>
            <select formControlName="userDays" required id="days" name="days">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
            </select>
        
            <label for="breakfast"><h4>Inkludert frokost? (300kr per dag)</h4></label>
            <mat-radio-group aria-label="breakfast" required formControlName="userBreakfast">
                <mat-radio-button value=true>Ja</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button value=false>Nei</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
            
            <section class="extraAct" formGroupName="extraAct">
                <h4>Kan vi friste med ekstraaktiviteter?</h4>
                <p><mat-checkbox formControlName="pool">Badebasseng</mat-checkbox></p>
                <p><mat-checkbox formControlName="kino">Kino</mat-checkbox></p>
                <p><mat-checkbox formControlName="resturant">Resturant</mat-checkbox></p>
            </section>
            <p>Totalpris: {{ totalPrice() }} kr.</p>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!hotelRegUser.valid" mat-radio-button>Bekreft</button>
        </form>
    </section>
</ng-template>
```

And I'm trying to access the "controls" thing inside extraAct, which is nested in hotelRegUser.

```
console.log(this.hotelRegUser["controls"]["extraAct"]);
```

This gives this:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJkGa.jpg)
If you can't open this link, it basically gives a "FormGroup", which has "controls" as one of the elements in it. I want to access this place because I'm hoping I'll be able to use a for each function to check whether or not the different statements in it is true.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You really want to use the getters for this. hotelRegUser.get(“extraAct”).value or deeper hotelRegUser.get([“extraAct”, “kino”])

Answer (score 0):

Since `extraAct` is a FormGroup you have to cast it as such to read the controls. The most common way is to do it in a getter:

```
get extraActFormGroup() {
  return this.hotelRegUser.controls.extraAct as FormGroup;
}
```

then to get the controls inside it:

```
console.log(this.extraActFormGroup.controls.pool.value)
```